# Screen orientation and values in manifest.xml

Tags: android, screen, orientation

I want to use all activities in my form in landscape or portrait.
When user select orientation - this is valid for all activities.
Tried with "behind" option orientation. According to Google - orientation will depend on previous activity.

My first activity use setRequestedOrientation to set selected from user orientation.

Next activities have to follow same orientation.
Do I have to put setRequestedOrientation in their code too? Or really on 'behind' parameter in manifest? Putting setRequestedOrientation may be cause onCreate again?

UPDATE:
Tried "portrait" and setRequestedOrientation() - result is onCreate was called 2 times.

Problem is in next activity -> because of "portrait" in first activity - android started next activity with same orientation. It ignores "landscape" orientation which was set by me.

Comment: It sure would be nice to be able to set this app-wide, perhaps with a per-activity override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I put check in onCreate:

```
m_bSkip = (this.getRequestedOrientation() != MyApp.sInstance.GetScreenOrientation());
if (m_bSkip)
  return;
```

When I enter oncreate and screen orientation is not desired - exit.
When I enter in onCreate and screen orientation is desired one - continue with initialization.
This fixes situation without need of keeping async task related to activity and check for new activity.
Of course all functions: onStart,onResume,onPausde,onStop... have to check this flag to avoid null pointer exception.

Answer (score 34):

If you want to have fixed orientation for your activities then you can use-

<del>android:screenOrientation="portrait"</del>

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
```

as an attribute to that activity in that manifest. But if you want to set the orientation runtime depending upon what was the previous orientation while launching the application, you need to check for the previous orientation in `onCreate()` and then set it to that value programmatically there itself using `setRequestedOrientation()`

**UPDATE:**
As pointed by @s.co.tt use `android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"` for a better support on tablets.

For more details on the different values for `android:screenOrientation` and what each of them do, look at the docs:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen

Comment: This will cause onCreate to be called twice :( and problem don't finish here. Next activiti starter as portrait because of 'portrait' of firts. Android ignores current state/landscape/

Comment: I tried debugging the code. It does NOT at all hit `onCreate()` twice. And next activity will also follow the same code in `onCreate()` to get the orientation.

Comment: Do not use `portrait`.  On some tablets (and probably other devices) your activity will display upside-down, as those devices believe that to be the correct default portrait orientation.  `sensorPortrait` (or in older APIs, the misspelled `sensorPortait`) will show your content in portrait only, but will rotate it to match the way in which the device is held by the user.

Comment: @s.co.tt Nice one, man! Couldn't figure out what some Activities were always one up and the others rotated based on the sensor.

Answer (score 8):

```
<activity
            android:name=".Android_mobile_infoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

Answer (score 5):

To handle the changes in orientation, add the following line in `AndroidManifest.xml`:
            `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`
under `<activity>` tag as shown below:-

```
   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        ----------
        ---------- >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        ----------
        </activity>
        ----------
    </application>
```

**Note**: Whenever there is a change in the configuration such as `orientation`, `screenLayout`, `screenSize`, etc., the activity is restarted and its `onCreate` method is called. To prevent this, we must handle any changes in configuration.

Answer (score 2):

## Do it programmatically, for example in an Activity base class

I tryed its working mobile and tablet. use anyone portrait or landscape.

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
   //or
   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

## manifest.xml inside application tag

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Login_Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

or

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Login_Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

Answer (score 2):

In Android studio 3.6.0

> android:screenOrientation="portrait"

will give you error you have to either specify

> android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" **or** android:screenOrientation="unspecified"

**fullSensor** Means either you have ON the "Rotate off" or not it will change the orientation based on you move the phone

**unspecified** Means if you have ON the Rotate off then it will stay only in that orientation and if not then it will change the orientation based on you move the phone.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I would recommend to setRequestedOrientation in every activity in onCreate method, onCreate won't be called again it's safe.

Comment: After set 'portrait' in manifest and call setRequestedOrientation() - onCreateWas called twice :( /till current and prfered orientation become the same/

Comment: I thought you fix for example 'portrait' and go to activity which also set 'portrait' this way preserving the orientation change if user  rotate the device. if go from one orientation to another - surely oncreate will be repeated. Could you describe your use case more detailed.

Comment: Firsta activity is started, but orientation have to be set depending on my setting. I read settings and set orientation of first activity/in onCreate/. Then start second activity. Second activity has to have same orientation because of flag "behind". But second activity have orientation same as declared in manifest for first one.

Comment: I am thinking what if you add the following property `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` to your first activity it should prevent re-creating the activity.

Answer (score 0):

go to Android Manifest editor , down there you will see MainActivity.java 
click on it , to the right - you will see a new window: scroll down and choose select orientation - "portrait"