# how to make cordova webview auto orientation

Tags: ios, cordova

I have extended an CordovaWebView in iOS and my custom view doesn't rotate automatically based on device orientation. I want to ask how can I do get my custom Webview responded to device orientation.

Answer (score 0):

if you are developing ios app with webview then you can set the webview autoresizing mask as

```
//Autoresizemask
       webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

or if you are developing phonegap application for ios or android, you need to modify the .plist file in ios and manifest file android.
On iPhone add this to -info.plist:

```
<dict>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>other orientations as you like</string>
    </array>

</dict>
```

on Android to AndroidManifest.xml

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801580/screen-orientation-and-values-in-manifest-xml)

Answer (score 0):

Create global function in your JavaScript file. This implementation allows rotate to any device orientation.

```
function shouldRotateToOrientation (orientation /*UIInterfaceOrientation*/) {
    // Return true if application is allow rotate to the requested orientation
    // Return false if this orientation is not currently allowed
    return true;
}
```