# Lock screen orientation to Portrait - React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native, screen-orientation

Tried lock screen orientation to portrait. It is easier to use and better experience for the customer.

I find AndroidManifest.xml and added `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to `activity` which is child of `application`.

This should work. But not. Any glue? Running app in Android via development server.

Comment: I believe the following post covers what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801580/screen-orientation-and-values-in-manifest-xml

Comment: @StevenLemos Thanks man, I'll try that.

Comment: @StevenLemos This works for the app, but the photos I take is still rotating. How disable that? Using RNCamera. I used `android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" `